# Use of are or is for this specific sentence

Tags: grammar, word-choice, grammatical-number

A friend said "some people are going downtown tonight" 
And then someone answered: who is 'some people'.
Is the correct response to ask who are some people? Or who is some people?

Comment: Who are "some people"?  Who are they?  Who are those people?

Comment: The _is_ refers to this specific group as a collection of people. _Who is (included in this group of) some people?_

Answer (score -1):

It's a common idiom, so common that it would be confusing to hear "Who *are* some people" in this context. Similarly, I'd say "Who's going downtown" or "who's in the group that's going", even if there are multiple people going.